# Video View setVideoUri fail in Android

Tags: android, uri, android-videoview, android-video-player

I have a `VideoView` that should start when the user click on `"play button"` but it doesn't work.

After some debug and some test, I see that if I start the video at the begin of the `OnCreate()`, it works perfect (it sets the URI).

But when I try to use the function `setVideoUri` inside of a Button `onClickListener`, it just doesn't work (it is like I don't call it).

There is no errors, or crash, just nothing happens.

Any ideas?

```
ImageView play2;
VideoView vView;
String video_url="URL OF THE VIDEO";
play2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            play.setVisibility(-1);  
            publicidad.setVisibility(-1);
            principal.setVisibility(-1);
            vView.setVisibility(1);
            play2.setVisibility(-1);
            vView.requestFocus();

            String a = urls_fotos[posicion][0];
            vView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(video_url));


            vView.setMediaController(new MediaController(ctx));


            vView.start();
            TextView ere= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulo);
            ere.setVisibility(-1);
            ere.setVisibility(1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are setting the listener to the wrong component?

```
ImageView play2;
play2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   //...
});
```

Code shows that you set the listener to a `ImageView` rather than a `Button`.
More over, that `ImageView` looks not initialized and a `NullPointerException` can be thrown if clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but ImageView is initializated I just didnt put the full code, and there is no error or something